# I want to do a simple drag-drop using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have  4 Buttons in browser,I  want to drag those Buttons and select those Buttons in mouse right click. is it possible. its like windows. i want to drag and select those Buttons in jquery in localhost.

Comment: `Please reply.` - Please do not add comments like this. They are useless. Besides that, your question is very vague - what are "bottoms"? Buttons? Give us a proper example on what exactly you want!

Comment: You'll need to tell us why you want to drag the buttons. You'll also need to explain why you're using the right click. Don't be discouraged by the negative votes :) Revise your question and include code of what you've tried (HTML and jQuery).

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at jQuery UI:

- [Draggable](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/)
- [Droppable](http://jqueryui.com/demos/droppable/)
- [Sortable](http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/)

I think either the first two or the last one is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 2):

You don't give many informations, so... just some links to help you in your search :

- http://api.jquery.com/mousedown/
- http://api.jquery.com/mousemove/
- http://api.jquery.com/mouseup/
- http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/